# AC dimmer not smooth dimming

Tags: arduino-micro

I am trying to create a phase control AC dimmer. But I am not able to achieve smooth dimming. I am using this guide for the circuit:

[Link](https://www.engineersgarage.com/contribution/automatic-street-lights-light-intensity-control-function)

On the zero detection part I am able to detect its zero crossing, but the output of the zero detection circuit is not a perfect square wave, it's kinda sinoidal.

So I have created my own code that when it reaches a value above 900 (very close to 0v) it will trigger the triac. I am using an Arduino Micro:

```cpp
#define TPulse 10
#define SW 7
#define ldr A0
#define zeroDetector A1

int x;
int delayDuration = 100;
long int count = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH); // pull up
  pinMode(TPulse, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SW, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(SW, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(TPulse, HIGH);
}

void loop() {

 delayDuration = map(analogRead(ldr), 0, 1024, 0, 9000);

 x = analogRead(zeroDetector);

 if (x <= 900)
    isr();

}

void isr () {
  digitalWrite(TPulse, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(delayDuration);
  digitalWrite(TPulse, HIGH);
}
```

I have calculated that in a 60Hz AC it will cross zero voltage 120 times a second thus the delay should be in range of 0 - 8300 microseconds.

But I am not able to achieve a smooth dimming, I am getting either of, flickering, fading (uncontrolled), and so on.

Is there something wrong with my analogy or am I missing something crucial?

I have replaced the LDR with a trimmer pot so I can easily adjust the resistance.

I trying to not use interrupt as of the moment. I am trying to achieve this type of dimming:

[image]

Comment: you can use a schmitt trigger to make a clean square wave from the analog signal. You might not want to use delays, which can cause sync issues if things get busy.

Comment: first sir i will agree with you that it works with interrupt. but i wanted to go with an approach without using interupt, i am confident that with 16mhz micro it can detect every zero cross

Comment: @dandavis , i dont think there is a work around to that since i will have to delay for a microsecond to chop the ac voltage

Comment: it depends on your "frame rate"; how many times loop() fires. I would only check the level-setting input 1 in 5 loop()s to keep the lanes open for your zero-cross.

Comment: I apologize sir i could not get what you mean by your last statement. by check level setting you mean the zero cross right?>

Comment: looks like you are leaving the triac turned on ...... `digitalWrite(TPulse, HIGH);` should be followed by `digitalWrite(TPulse, LOW);` ....... the triac shuts itself off automatically at zero crossing once it is triggered ..... you only need to send it a short pulse to trigger it

Comment: Yes, jsotola 30 is right, you leave the triac gate on until next zero crossing but the short delay from real zero to detection might cause the tyristor to open